# Can I use splines and bones together in the same rig?

Tags: rigging, bones, bezier-curves

I have model of an animal I'm building. It will have bones to animate the limbs, the neck, and the jaws. However, I want the tail to be less rigid. So, can I use a bezier curve and bones together?

[image: proposed model]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from doing both.  This situation comes up from time to time when rigging polygonal hair to a character: the hair usually has spline control, and the body is made of bones.  Just make sure your parenting hierarchy and weight paint makes sense.  For simplicity, you may want to make the tail and body two discreet objects with their own deform modifier.

Also, there is the spline IK modifier for bones, in which a spline controls a series of bones.  So it's kind of mixing both.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't thinking about the latter part (To be honest I've not done a boat load of animation over the years).